# Is an optional Promise for Firebase possible in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, swift, firebase

I know how to do it in Swift, but for Javascript as a beginner I am struggling with this. Lets say this is my function:

```
const prom3 = Promise? //this is wrong, I know. Normally in Swift this is an optional
if (statement){
pickerActive = true
 prom3 = pathToLottery.once("value", function(values) {
   //some function
    })
     }
    if (pickerActive == false){ //normally set to false
    return 
    }else{
        return prom3! //not working because this is Swift syntax. How do to this kind of Swift behavior in Javascript? Is it possible?
    }
```

A possibility is to declare prom3 inside the main scoop, but I want it to make it optional. Is this possible?

This is the type it should be, maybe that helps:

```
const prom3: Promise<any> (if I put the function inside the main scoop and hovering my mouse over prom3)
```

Declaring prom3 without the questionmark and ! will throw an error when executing.

Comment: a function shouldn't return either a promise or a value. Just always return the promise. In both cases you'd then be able to access the value using .then

Comment: When the statement is met, a set of data will be downloaded in the .once. I think it is unnecessary to download that data every time and than check the values if needed. The set of data can contain a lot of data, and the function can be executed a lot of times. The statement will be executed only once in a thousand times. That is why I think it is a good idea to only check values if needed. Do you think it is bad practice of what I am doing? I am quite new to Javascript and promises.

Comment: I agree that it would be a bad idea to download the data over and over if there is no reason for it to have changed between calls, and that's not what i was suggesting. It is in fact possible to create a promise that is resolved with a certain value without going back to the data source.,

Comment: Unfortunately though i'm completely unfamiliar with swift, so i might be missing the exact functionality you are going for.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://howtofirebase.com/promises-for-firebase-bbb9d0d595ed

Comment: @KevinB in Swift a value can be optional, which can be safety unwrapped to check if there is a value in it. If yes -> return prom3, if no -> return.

Comment: @GabeRogan I will have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Which... you can technically do with javascript, it's just not often done. Because now, after doing so, you'll have to detect whether the returned value is a promise or a value, and then treat said response differently in both cases.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by 'whether the returned value is a promise or a value'. I need to check if the value (which is a Boolean, pickerActive) is true or false. If it is true, I know for sure const prom3 is a promise because it is being executed and defined. It pickerActive is false, prom3 would remain untouched and unused.

Answer (score 1):

You can structure your code in a way that doesn't require optional values, as below:

```
  if (statement){
    pickerActive = true

     const prom3 = pathToLottery.once('value') 

    prom3.then(snap => {
    // some func that has access to data at pathToLottery
    const data = snap.val()
    return 
    })

  } else {
  return
  }
```

Check out this video for more info:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgZIb6Uwpjc&t=35s